# How can I get MySQL function code at the time of stored procedure execution

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to get one of my Mysql function script (code) into temporary variable at the time of stored procedure execution. Once I get the script then I want to insert that function script into my temporary table for some reason.

By below query I can get function body from "Begin" to "End" only but I want whole script please help me.

```
SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION into @temp 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_TYPE="function" 
AND ROUTINE_SCHEMA="dataabse_name" and ROUTINE_NAME = "function_name";
```

Thank you in advance..

Ronak

Comment: In application you can use SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE/SHOW CREATE FUNCTION statement.

Comment: Thnx for help.SHOW CREATE FUNCTION command gives me my function whole script but how do I dump it into my temporary variable? @Devart

Comment: Read result of `SHOW CREATE PROCEDURE` in the application, generate and execute a script like this `SET @var = CREATE PROCEDURE...`.

Comment: I think we can not dump above script into temporary variable using "SHOW" statement. We must use "Select" statement to do so. Can you please help me what should I do in my case? @Devart